# Changing arrow colour in smartdiagram

Tags: tikz-pgf, color, tikz-arrows, smartdiagram

The `smartdiagram` package appears to have a default convention that an arrow in a circular diagram takes the colour of the *destination* block. Is there a way to choose instead the colour of the *source* block as the colour of the arrow.
For instance, in this example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{smartdiagram}
\begin{document}
\smartdiagramset{set color list={red!50,orange!50,green!50}}
\smartdiagram[circular diagram:clockwise]{Red,Orange,Green}
\end{document}
```

I want the arrow from "Red" to "Orange" to be red instead of orange. In other words, I want to advance all arrow colours one step clockwise.

Is there a single key or other simple option to do this? If there isn't might I suggest it through this forum please?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz,convert=false]{standalone}
\usepackage{smartdiagram}
\makeatletter
\smartdiagramset{
  flip arrow colors/.style={
    /tikz/diagram arrow type/.prefix code={%
      \edef\col{\@nameuse{color@\xi}}%
    }
  }
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\smartdiagramset{set color list={red!50,orange!50,green!50}}
\smartdiagram[circular diagram:clockwise]{Red,Orange,Green}

\smartdiagramset{flip arrow colors}
\smartdiagram[circular diagram:clockwise]{Red,Orange,Green}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]
 [image]

Comment: Nice answer. But some explanations would be nice.

Comment: @ThorstenDonig I don't have time right now, but the code for the `circular diagram` stores the value of the current element in `\xi`  and and calculates the next value in `\xj` and defines `\col` in dependence of `\xj`. The `diagram arrow type` style uses the key `\col` (i.e. `color=\col`). We simply overwrite `\col` with the current color name before (`prefix`) the `color=\col` key is used.

Comment: Is it possible to create tree diagrams easily with smartdiagram? like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/v53dD.png

Comment: @skan Unless the `smartdiagram` package got a big overhaul in the last two and a half years you are probably better of with one of the tree packages (like `forest`) or the in-house tree-creating mechanism of TikZ itself.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel OK thanks, then I'll use forest or maybe I'll create the diagrams with an external program and export it to svg.

Answer (score 6):

Not really a "simple key" as requested, but no sorcery though because not so complex. There are two things to be done.

1. A redefinition of the `arrow style`.
2. Altering the sequence of the nodes.

The result could then look like this.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{smartdiagram}

\smartdiagramset{arrow style=->}

\begin{document}
  \smartdiagramset{set color list={orange!50,red!50,green!50}}
  \smartdiagram[circular diagram:clockwise]{Orange,Red,Green}
\end{document}
```

The problem is that now `clockwise` is a bit irritating. This is due to the unconventional initial definition `arrow style=<-` for the direction of the arrows.

---

[image]