# My code about smartdiagram has some problems

Tags: beamer, smartdiagram

My code about smartdiagram has some problems.
I would like to ask people who handle Latex, in particular, smartdiagram part.

```
\begin{frame}{}
    \begin{beamerboxesrounded}[upper=uppercol,lower=lowercol,shadow=true]{Example 2}
        \begin{minipage}[c][3cm]{.5\textwidth}
            \begin{center}
                \smartdiagramset{
                    border color=none,
                    back arrow disabled=true
                }
                \smartdiagram[flow diagram:horizontal]{
                    $X$,
                    Noisy channel,
                    $Y$,
                    $f(\cdot)$,
                    $Z$
                }
            \end{center}
        \end{minipage}

        ...
    \end{beamerboxesrounded}
\end{frame}
```

[image: imge]

I want to draw like the following image:
[image: Hope]

Moreover, I do not know why the size (width) exceeds the page even though I use minipage environment.

So far, I used to draw image in powerpoint, to save it with pdf extension, to open the pdf file in illustrator program, and re-save the image with eps extension.

Now, I think it's time that I learn to use smartdiagram!!

Thank you for reading my question.

Comment: It makes it much easier for people to help if you post complete code we can compile.

Comment: @cfr Okay, I understand it. From now on, I will post complete code when I ask a question. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To add text (Y) above the arrow, you can use the `additions` option of `smartdiagram` package (see the [package documentation](http://texdoc.net/show.php?pkg=smartdiagram) for more information).

Concerning your size problem: If you put a something inside a `minipage` which is larger than said `minipage`, it will simply stuck out and won't be magically resized. If you want the digram to be smaller, you could try to use `\resizebox` or similar.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}

\usepackage{tikz} 
\usepackage{smartdiagram}
\usesmartdiagramlibrary{additions}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{}
    \begin{beamerboxesrounded}[upper=uppercol,lower=lowercol,shadow=true]{Example 2}
        \begin{minipage}[c][3cm]{\textwidth}
            \centering
                \smartdiagramset{
                    border color=none,
                    back arrow disabled=true,
                                    additions={
                                      additional item offset=-7mm,
                                      additional item fill opacity=0
                                    }
                }
                \smartdiagramadd[flow diagram:horizontal]{
                    $X$,
                    Noisy channel,
                    $f(\cdot)$,
                    $Z$
                }
                {
                        above right of module2/$Y$~~~,
                }
        \end{minipage}
    \end{beamerboxesrounded}
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much!! It works. Can I ask one? Why $Y$ is not displayed if I use center environment instead of centering you suggested? And isn't there any method X and Z also without opacity

Comment: @Danny_Kim I don't see any difference if I use `\begin{center} ... \end{center}` instead. Can you put an example in  your question?

Comment: @Danny_Kim As for changing the colour of X and Z, you could do this with a colour list (http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/126460/changing-arrow-colour-in-smartdiagram) but this leaves behind the shadow. Maybe you should have a look into the documentation.

Comment: @Danny_Kim I think it would be easier to use Ti*k*Z directly in that case. `smartdiagram` is great for quickly drawing diagrams of certain kinds, but it is not designed to be infinitely flexible. That is, if you want a diagram not of one of those kinds, it is easier to just draw the diagram rather than fighting `smartdiagram`.

Comment: @Danny_Kim Also if Z should be without colour, what colour do you expect the arrow to have?

Comment: @cfr Aha~? Ti$k$Z? I've never used that one. Thank you for noticing me that package. I want to learn to use Latex well from seniors. Getting used to Latex myself is too hard :(.

Comment: @samcarter Ah, in my desktop, centering and begin{center} both works. I don't know why $Y$ is not displayed when I use begin{center} in my tablet.

Comment: @samcarter And I hope to diagram like what I draw manually. $X$, $Y$, and $Z$ without box. only channel and function with box

Comment: @Danny_Kim `smartdiagram` is based on Ti*k*Z. It gives you certain styles, but you can roll your own.