# How can I make the arrows of a smartdiagram in the color of the box they are from, not to?

Tags: smartdiagram

I want `smartdiagram` to use the color of the preceding box also for the arrow, instead of the box it is leading to. Therefore in this image:

[image]

I want the green arrow to be red, the blue one to be green, the orange one to be blue and the red one to be orange.

How can I achieve this? Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{smartdiagram}

\tikzset{
    every shadow/.style={
        fill=none,
        shadow xshift=0pt,
        shadow yshift=0pt}
}

\tikzset{module/.append style={top color=\col,bottom color=\col}}

\smartdiagramset{%
    module shape=rectangle,
    text color=white,
    border color=none,
}

\smartdiagramset{set color list={red,green,blue,orange}}

\begin{document}
\sffamily
\smartdiagram[flow diagram:horizontal]{elem1,elem2,elem3,elem4}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/126481/197451

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{smartdiagram}

\tikzset{
    every shadow/.style={
        fill=none,
        shadow xshift=0pt,
        shadow yshift=0pt}
}

\tikzset{module/.append style={top color=\col,bottom color=\col}}

\smartdiagramset{%
    module shape=rectangle,
    text color=white,
    border color=none,
}
\makeatletter
\smartdiagramset{
    flip arrow colors/.style={
        /tikz/diagram arrow type/.prefix code={%
            \edef\col{\@nameuse{color@\xi}}%
        }
    }
}
\smartdiagramset{flip arrow colors}

\begin{document}
\sffamily
\smartdiagram[flow diagram:horizontal]{elem1,elem2,elem3,elem4}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @TobiBS if you found the answer helpful feel free to upvote